# Where to read about timing limitations of services/functions?

Tags: android-studio, service, alarmmanager

I'm trying to find the best way to trigger a service every 1s (ideally, every 0.5s would be even better).  I put together an app using AlarmManager and Broadcast receiver that's very similar to this one:

```
https://erev0s.com/blog/run-android-service-background-reliably-every-n-seconds/
```

It worked very well but I found when I tried to go from 15s down to, say 1s, it capped it at every 5s.  I'm guessing there's a limit built into Android (I'm currently running it on Android 12) that likely prevents the system from calling functions too often so as to not eat up too much CPU and/or battery.  Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation on where this limitation is set, if it's a limitation of Android services or if it's a limitation of AlarmManager.

Does anyone know where I can find this information?  Or if there's another module I would want to use for regular service calls that would allow me to trigger a functions every 0.5-1s?

Thanks!